# Trouble with text alignment on HUAWEI Devices

Tags: java, android, xml, right-to-left, huawei-mobile-services

I have a trouble with text alignment on **HUAWEI** Devices.
My Text widgets have right text alignment `(with android:gravity="start")`
Application Tag:

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".ShopApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    />
```

And TextView XML (for Example)

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_value"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="start"
   android:text="23.000.000.097"
   android:textColor="@color/background"
   android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

Application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_red_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

When i set gravity END - text appears on left side of `TextView`.

[1 - textview with android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:gravity="end", 2 - textview with wrap_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOc8i.png)

Maybe you know how fix it?

I want have standart start - left / end - right gravity

Thx!

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/hMLNX5)

Comment: Try to use `gravity="left"` or `"right"`

Comment: When i set gravity left/right - it's works, but i use default alert dialog and title in alert dialog also appear on right side

Comment: Sorry your question is unclear. What do you need to fix?

Comment: Maybe somebody know how fix this forse rtl mode?

Comment: Please add screenshots

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: @BorisVedensky Check device locale (some locales are RTL), check developer option -> force rtl. Try to disable rtl support for app

Answer (score 0):

Solution founded!
Huawei have strange behaviour, when i set default locale (it enabled force RTL)
When i set Language locale (US,RU,ZH,etc), instead of "default" - RTL disabled